# get distinct rows from datatable using Linq (distinct with mulitiple columns)

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects

I am trying to distinct on multiple columns  and get datarows from datatable. but getting error.

```
 Dim query As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = 
            (From row As DataRow In SourceTable.AsEnumerable() _
             Select row.Field(Of String)("ColumnName1"),
                    row.Field(Of String)("ColumnName2") ).Distinct()
```

below error:

```
Unable to cast object of type '<DistinctIterator>d__7a`1[System.String]' 
to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Data.DataRow]'.
```

I want another datatable with distinct row based on given columns from SourceTable.

Comment: you could use the distinct support in datatable - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataset/thread/ed9c6a6a-a93e-4bf5-a892-d8471b84aa3b/   ToTable() has an overload which lets you specify whether or not to return only distinct values, and a params string[] argument to specify which columns you want in the new table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This one then

```
Dim query = From q In (From p In dt.AsEnumerable() Select New With {.col1= p("ColumnName1"), .col2 = p("ColumnName2")}) Select q.col1, q.col2 Distinct
```

Comment: How to user 'query' objects. I mean How to iterate that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (a bit of a guess on my part):

```
Dim query As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) =  
        (From row As DataRow In SourceTable.AsEnumerable().Distinct()  _ 
         Select row.Field(Of String)("ColumnName1"), 
                row.Field(Of String)("ColumnName2"))
```

Comment: Ah shit I should have paid more attention to the error message. I've got it now. Your problem isn't your SQL syntax - it's the datatype you expect since you're marking it as an Enumerable collection of DataRows when you're projecting tuples which contain a pair of strings.

Comment: Change the syntax so you're projecting a new DataRow with each of the strings added as columns - either that or strip the As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) and just accept the implict type as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var distinctRows = (from DataRow dRow in dTable.Rows
                    select new col1=dRow["dataColumn1"],col2=dRow["dataColumn2"]}).Distinct();
```

this is in C#. Convert it into vb.net

Comment: You're missing a curly brace at the front of your LINQ projection, but I get your meaning.

Comment: This one is not returing distinct columns