# remove duplicate rows in datatable using VB net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, duplicates

I have dt1, dt2 DataTables. I have merged them to dt1 by using
dt1.Merge(dt2)

But there are multiple duplicate rows and I don't have primarykey for those rows, how to eliminate duplicate records?

Comment: Are they 100% identical or just mostly identical?

Comment: This Q+A will show you a method:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242892/select-distinct-rows-from-datatable-in-linq

Comment: If you haven't unique value in the row, then you will need to compare between all columns and based on the result remove duplicates