# Using distinct on all columns in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework. I am trying to write select query in EF which selects distinct columns from a view. I am using following code

```
List<ClientDTO> oClients = new List<ClientDTO>();

oClients = (from p in context.vwClients
            where (p.ClientNumber == ClientNumber) && p.isDeleted == true
            select new ClientDTO
                   {
                       ClientNumber = p. ClientNumber,
                       IncomeClassId = p.IncomeClassId,
                       FullClientName = p. FullClientName,
                       CountryId = p.CountryId,
                       ProductId = p.ProductId,
                       ProductName = p.ProductName,
                       ProductShortName = p.ProductShortName,
                       isDeleted = p. isDeleted
                   }).OrderBy(x => x. FullClientName).Distinct().ToList();
```

It still returns duplicate rows. When I write the SQL query with distinct on all columns, it does return distinct rows.

Is there any way to get distinct of all columns used in above code?

Answer (score 0):

Using anonymous objects should work.

```
var oClients = (from p in context.vwClients where (p.ClientNumber == ClientNumber) && p.isDeleted == true
                                select new ClientDTO
                                {

                                   ClientNumber = p. ClientNumber,
                                   IncomeClassId = p.IncomeClassId,
                                   FullClientName = p. FullClientName,
                                   CountryId = p.CountryId,
                                   ProductId = p.ProductId,
                                   ProductName = p.ProductName,
                                   ProductShortName = p.ProductShortName,
                                   isDeleted = p. isDeleted
                                }
                        ).Select(i => new {i.ClientNumber, i.IncomeClassId, i.FullClientName, i.CountryId, i.ProductId, i.ProductName, i.ProductShortName, i.isDeleted}).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the lambda expression for the required result :

```
List<ClientDTO> oClients =context.vwClients.Where(p=> p.ClientNumber == ClientNumber && p.isDeleted == true)        
                    .Select(p=> new ClientDTO
                    {
                                    ClientNumber = p. ClientNumber,
                                   IncomeClassId = p.IncomeClassId,
                                   FullClientName = p. FullClientName,
                                   CountryId = p.CountryId,
                                   ProductId = p.ProductId,
                                   ProductName = p.ProductName,
                                   ProductShortName = p.ProductShortName,
                                   isDeleted = p. isDeleted
                    }).OrderBy(p => p. FullClientName).Distinct().ToList();
```

For more example [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242892/select-distinct-rows-from-datatable-in-linq)