# How to get distinct values from data table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, distinct, asenumerable

I am trying to `return` an `array with *distinct records*. But this piece of code isn’t working. What am I doing wrong?

```
return table.AsEnumerable().Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default).ToArray();
```

Comment: Please describe `not working`.

Comment: what you are doing is giving you distinct rows.  Is there an element in the row you want to be distinct?  What is it you want to do.

Comment: It is not returning distinct rows. I see duplicates.

Comment: Yes I want an element “x” in the row to be distinct.

Comment: It depends on which fields/columns from your table you wants a distinct data.
Reference taken from similar questions on stack overflow.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242892/select-distinct-rows-from-datatable-in-linq

Answer (score 0):

```
table
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<DataType>("FieldName"))
    .Select(group => group.First())
    .ToArray()
```

Comment: I  assumed OP wants to get distinct by one field, since the question was ambiguous, lot of assumptions.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I meant that it this would be a better answer if instead of just a line of code, you provided some explaination as to why this code answers the question.

Comment: Alright, I am sorry, I suppose it is straight forward, if OP wants to get distinct by one field, then group by that field, and get distinct groups.